# Calculate next point on sphere a certain distance away

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spheres

I have a sphere where I know the radius, origin and a single point $p^1$ on the surface by its cartesian coordinates ('world' x/y/z).

I'm struggling trying to calculate the position of another point $p^2$ on the surface a certain x/y spherical distance away from $p^1$.

Any pointers in the right direction or solutions would be much appreciated :)

[Image explaining what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEujb.png)

Comment: If you know the coordinates of $P_1$ and the difference in $x,y$ coordinates for $P_2$ from those of $P_1$, then that gives you the $x,y$ coordinates of $P_2$. You get the $z$-coordinate by setting its distance from the centre to the radius.

Comment: I only know the spherical x/y (polar/elevation?) distance I wish to travel along the surface from p1 to p2, so if I just add the x/y values it wont be the correct distance between the points :)

Comment: What do you mean by "x/y spherical distance"?

Comment: The distance along the sphere, and not just directly between the two points cutting through the sphere.